# How to connect external display to MacBook Pro without a cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have **MacBook Pro 16”** and want to connect an external display, but it is not convenient for me to plug in a cable to my MacBook.
Is there a some way to use a wireless connection? I don’t expect 4 or 8K, at least FullHD.

Do I need to buy **Apple TV**, special display or some wireless connector?

Comment: See:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a few wireless dongles and other devices in the past and they've been hit and miss due to driver issues and other complications.

By far the easiest method is to use a **AppleTV** and use AirPlay to mirror or extend the display to the screen.

You would connect the AppleTV to the display using HDMI. After setting it all up you would then click the AirPlay icon in the upper right of your Mac's screen and select your AppleTV from the choices.

If your WiFi is nice and strong for both units, you should be good to go.